# Clone database programmatically and link it to a new workgroup in Androi

Tags: android, mysql, database

Good day friends,
I'm a newbie Android developer and I would greatly appreciate your help. I am finishing my first project, which consists of a business-type application in which Service Orders can be generated for relatively small groups that belong to the same company. In order not to confuse the information of one company with another, the application requires that the remote database be cloned for each company when it is downloaded by the Admin user. The Admin user will have to add/invite the other users of the group, who will receive an email with instructions to join the group after downloading the application. My question is: How can I automatically clone the database every time the APP is downloaded by a new workgroup?

In the test enviroment the application works fine with a workgroup, but I don't know how to clone the database when be necessary

Comment: Just to make sure yo have a MySQL server and users of different work groups connect through your app to it? o you use the user management of MySQL, so each workgroup gets an mysql connect string  and for each user (or workgroup) a MySQL user account?